# How does account name actions work on EOS?

Tags: account-name

I hear that we can create 12 character names before the launch of the mainnet for free. What if the name that I'm looking to buy is FACEBOOK. How can I acquire it through account name auctions?

I see users bidding for their account name of choice here https://toolkit.genereos.io/names. But when will the bids end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great article about the name bidding.

> Premium name bidding does not begin until 14 days after the mainnet unlocks. (The mainnet will unlock and officially reward block production once 15% of the total EOS supply has been staked and voted for block producers).
>
> Only one name will be awarded each day - the name awarded is the one that has the highest bid of all names as of that day.

https://steemit.com/eos/@genereos/name-bidding-and-premium-names-on-eos

Answer (score -1):

The bid end in 24 hours if no higher bid provided.